# rename values from df.columns

Tags: python, pandas

suppose I have a dataframe column values as shown below

```
print(df.columns)
Index([  "CustomerID",  "CompanyName",  "ContactName", "ContactTitle",
            "Address",         "City",       "Region",   "PostalCode",
            "Country",        "Phone",          "Fax"],
      dtype='object')
```

I want to remove quotes from the values.
This is what I have tried:

```
for cols in list(df.columns):
    new_col = str(cols).replace('"','').replace('"','')
    cols.rename(index={cols: new_col})
```

Any solution will be helpfull.

Comment: But `"` are not shown, why need remove them?

Comment: @jezrael for ex quote " in "CustomerID" i want to remove it

Comment: OK, what is `print (df.columns[0][0])` ?

Comment: this is programming basics - strings are contained in quotes in python (in many programming languages).  It's part of the syntax if the language.  quotes can also be included in strings,  if you wanted to remove these it could make sense,  changing syntax and semantics of python doesn't....

Comment: You have made the rookie mistake of confusing the CONTENT of a field with the REPRESENTATION of that field.  The fields do not contain quotes, of course.  Your code has to include quotes, because that's how strings are created in Python, but they are not part of the field names.

Comment: @shee quotes represents string values, think logically if you remove quotes how are you going to store the values? You will be left with my_list= [CustomerID] and python will assume CustomerID is a variable which is not true

Comment: @jezrael it says TypeError: 'Name' object is not subscriptable

Comment: OK, what is `print (df.columns[0])` ?

Comment: @jezrael "CustomerID"

Comment: It is weird `print (df.columns[0][0])` failed. It should be `C`

Comment: @jezrael is there any rename function?

Comment: Hmmm, what you need is impossible. check comments above why

Comment: @shee What is the output of `print(df.head().to_dict())`?

Comment: What is the `Name` there? Is that a custom class you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Its a string type for .columns, If you remove quote its invalid.

Comment: but if i print **print (df.columns[0])** it shows "CustomerID"

Comment: Try to remove the quotes and see what happens. It will show an error. This is just how the language works, there is no way around it.